# What defined the ownership of a treasure in Jesus' time?

Tags: gospels, parables

Matthew 13:43 reads:

> The kingdom of heaven is like treasure hidden in a field, which someone found and hid; then in his joy he goes and sells all that he has and buys that field.

One is intrigued by the step-by-step action of the finder. He could have easily taken the treasure. That prospect leads one to believing that there was some law which defined the ownership of a treasure, both legal and moral. (These days it usually goes to the Government, whoever be the one who finds it, and whatever be the place it is found in!).

Are there any studies into the legal system prevailing at the time of Jesus that defined the ownership of a treasure ?

Comment: It is unlikely the Catholic Church has done any such study as it is just not relevant to Catholic theology. You might find an answer at https://judaism.stackexchange.com where they are deeply interested in the history and application of Jewish law.

Comment: I don't think you need to scope Catholic here. It's a history question.

Comment: If the finder was honest, he would have informed the owner of the field and pleaded for a share . If he was a thief, he would have stolen it in the night. He in fact, took a great risk of hiding the treasure and returning with the sale proceeding of all his properties , in order to claim it . My conclusion, therefore, is: there was some legitimate weightage , say 50-70% given to the finder of the treasure on  its  ownership, which would place him in an advantageous position over the first owner of the field.